# value of $g(3)$ in functional equation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> If $$\int^{2x+\cos(\pi x)}_{0}g(t)dt=x^2$$for all real $x$ and $g(x)$ is continuous function. Then $g(3)$ equals

What i try: using Newton leibnitz formula

$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int^{2x+\cos x}_{0}g(t)dt\bigg)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$$

$$g(2x+\cos \pi x)(2-\pi\sin(\pi x)=2x$$

When i put $x=1$. Then $g(1)=1$

When i put $x=2$. Then $g(5)=2$

How do i calculate $g(3)$

Help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $x = \frac 32$ gives
$$g\left(3 + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\right) = \frac{3}{2 - \pi \sin \left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)}$$
which hence gives
$$g(3) = \frac{3}{2-\pi(-1)} = \frac{3}{2+\pi}.$$

Comment: Thanks hdighfan.Is it not $\pi\sin\bigg(\frac{3\pi}{2}\bigg)=-\pi$

Comment: Ah, my bad, i forgot about the $\pi$. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much hdighfan got it.